# Deserialize JSON string to object that's also in the JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
{
    "Cats": [
        {
            "Name": "Max",
            "Color": "Brown"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Cherry",
            "Color": "Black"
        }
    ],
    "Owners": [
        {
            "Name": "Tom",
            "Cat": "Max"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Cindy",
            "Cat": "Cherry"
        }
    ]
}
```

Instead of getting the string value of Tom's Cat, and then doing a second operation to get the cat's color, is it possible to deserialize this JSON so that I can just do:

```
var tomsCatsColor = Rootobject.Owners[0].Cat.Color;
```

Comment: There's no out of the box way to do this, you'll just have to know that you are referencing something in the JSON when you deserialize and link it then

Comment: I don't think you can do this easily with straight JSON, but when taking in the values, it might make sense to have the JavaScript build maps out of their names. For instance, `catNameMap = {"Cherry": {"Name": "Cherry", "Color": "Black"}};`. Then, it would actually be pretty easy to get individual cats/owners based on relevant name information; `catNameMap[owner.Cat].Color`

Answer (score 0):

You can give the user a cat identifier, this will look something like:

```js
{
    "Cats": [
        {
            "Name": "Max",
            "Color": "Brown"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Cherry",
            "Color": "Black"
        }
    ],
    "Owners": [
        {
            "Name": "Tom",
            "Cat": 0
        },
        {
            "Name": "Cindy",
            "Cat": 1
        }
    ]
}

var tomsCatsColor = Rootobject.Cats[Rootobject.Owners[0].Cat].Color;
```